# C# : How to show logged in User data

Tags: c#, sql-server, desktop-application

I want to show a report in GridView in a C# application.Where Users who have logged in can see the data/ access the data based on his id.

```
private void generateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=INCEPSYS-SE\TEST;Initial Catalog=Employee;Integrated Security=True");
                connection.Open();
           SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Employees.Name, Phones.Receive FROM Phones JOIN Employees
        where Date ='" +reportDatePicker.Value.Date + "' ON Employees.EmployeeID=Phones.EmployeeID " , connection);
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                    reportGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
                    reportGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;   
      }
```

How to  do the authentication with the following code?

Comment: What does the code have to do with the question? You ask about user data but post  an `Employee` query that's open to SQL injection. How is this related to authentication?

Comment: Agreed, Question and the code in question is different.

Comment: I wanted to ask in it in general ..Yup I'm working in Employee database..But the main focus of the Question in authentication where only only authorize user only can see the data..That's it.
hope you guys understand..Thank you!

Comment: Understood, but for your future questions. Please put only the Code that you have searched and tried to resolve the issue but couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Web.Hosting;

    using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
    {
                 PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
                 user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, txtUser.Text.Trim());
    }
```

Here *user.EmployeeID* will give you the ID. Use this to filter your query in gridview. I hope this is what you wanted.